# Given the anti-slavery policy in Winterfell, isn't Bran a particularly dark character?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Is Bran, a male highborn, entitled to a hand servant? Hodor, Bran's servant, is never offered the best food, time to rest, or ever thanked. His efforts are not even recognized. Bran can even snatch Hodor's body to amuse himself.

Bran abuses a mentally disabled person with impunity, and no one challenges Bran.

1. does this demonstrate people are afraid of Bran and won't challenge him?
2. The acceptable abuse of Hodor is there to show use how much modern civilization has advanced? In the 21st century, Bran would not be allowed to abuse Hodor.
3. Hodor really does have free will and wants to be Bran's servant?
4. Hodor is not a servant. Rather he is "something else"?

Comment: WRT "Given the anti-slavery policy in Winterfell": [slavery is prohibited in mainland Westeros](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Slavery#Westeros), though one could argue that serfdom (i.e. peasants etc.) isn't that much better (check the Tyrion quote at the link). Note that the Ironborn have thralls and salt wives (check the link).

Comment: Another reason to think Bran is dark and getting darker: Varamyr Sixskins is introduced as a very dark character who none-the-less is very reluctant to take over another human's body, and only attempts it when near death. Meanwhile, Bran is doing it casually. [And "Never fear the darkness, Bran... Darkness will make you strong"... there's a theory that these are clues to a big upcoming twist...](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Great_Other)

Comment: I think it is a valid question, e.g. "Doesn't Hodor have free will?", but put it a much too inflammatory way. There is no mention anywhere that Hodor gets substandard food, that he does not get time to rest,  that he is never thanked, or that his efforts are not recognized. Rather the opposite, I would say. Everyone is always nice to Hodor, and he helps out because he is a "friendly giant". Calling Bran dark when he does not have a malignant bone in his body is rather far fetched.

Comment: @TLP sure. Bran is good now. But, I suspect his powerful magic will corrupt him and turn him to the dark side. No matter how nice Bran is, absolute power corrupts absolutely.

Comment: @runfaster Bran's power is not absolute, though, nor do I think it will be. One thing that I do agree with is that there are a lot of hinting towards Bran going toward the dark side, such as "the darkness" quote above, Melisandre's conclusion in her vision, the "blood" that Bran ate, Varamyr's spirit, etc. However I think it far too unlikely that GRRM would make Bran a badguy, seeing as he is, just about, the main protagonist (the first chapter in the series is Bran's).

Comment: One thing GRRM has made clear consistently (in both interviews and his writing) is that he loves to surprise readers and hates feeling like anything about his writing is "predictable". So, him slowly turning the series' first protagonist into its cheif villian would be (ironically...) not a huge surprise

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is Bran, a male highborn, entitled to a hand servant?

I think the simplest answer that can be given here is: Yes, if he can afford it. 
Highborn people with money can afford hand servants, so they can have as many as they want.

I wouldn't call Hodor a slave. Slaves are like those people Daenerys meets on Slaver's Bay (and releases them). People that have no freedom at all. Slaves are what people used Africans for on the U.S. plantations so many years ago.

Hodor would be more like an in-house help or servant. Rich people still have this kind of help nowadays. They don't feed them the best food, but they are free.

I don't recall any mention of Hodor making complains (I know he can't talk, but he does express his feelings). So, he must think that his job is okay. He is a mentally challenged person that would have trouble at pretty much any job. But instead, he lives and works with a family that respects and loves him. I actually find that good-hearted.

1. I don't think anyone is afraid of Bran. Everyone sees him as a crippled child. Spoilers for season 4 and book 5:

> they don't know about his powers yet; but still, we don't know if people will be afraid of him when they find out.

2. Like I mentioned above I don't think Bran is actually abusing Hodor. He does what every person with a servant would do. Also, take note that Game of Thrones doesn't take place in the 21st century. It takes place in a fictional Medieval-themed world. That means that people don't have the human rights you and I do.
3. We don't really know how much free will Hodor has or how he ended up working for the Starks. The fact that his grandma (Old Nan) worked there for many years might have played some role.  Also, like I mentioned above, we pretty much can assume that he wouldn't be the best in some other work
4. The Starks actually feel like he is a part of their family.

It would also be good to point out that there is a difference between the meaning of the words 'slave' and 'servant'. To put it as simply as I can:

- **servant** is someone who *willingly and voluntarily* serves someone.
- **slave** is someone who *involuntarily and against his will* serves someone.

Comment: I am so anti-Bran, I definitely need to step back and think about your thoughtful answer. thank you.

Comment: One could argue that Hodor is incapable of consent, which makes him somewhat less of a servant...